# Interact with application on desktop/icon level (OS X)

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, appkit

So I've figured out how to draw my application at icon level by setting my window's level to `kCGDesktopIconWindowLevelKey`. Works flawlessly.

The problem I'm having is interaction. When the application starts and the window is focused everything is fine, but the moment I let go of it and focus another application or some other icon, I can never focus the window again. It's as if it were merged into the desktop...

Anyone had a similar issue and knows how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug I encountered as well, and it all started when Lion was released. In order to counteract this, you need to add on one or two levels onto the default key. Like so:

```
window.level = kCGDesktopIconWindowLevelKey + 1;
```